# How to clone/copy records using apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, clone

**Trigger**

```java
trigger TRG_LinkCampaing on Test_Campaign__c (after insert,after update) {

    
    set<Id> ParID = new set<Id>();
    
    
    for(Test_Campaign__c TestCamp : Trigger.new)
    {
      ParID.add(TestCamp.Core_Campaign_Model__c);
    }
    List<Test_Scenario__c> TS = [Select Id , Test_Campaign__c from Test_Scenario__c where  Test_Campaign__c In :ParID ];
    List<Test_Campaign__c> TC = [Select Id,name from Test_Campaign__c where Id = : Trigger.new];

     List<Test_Scenario__c> TestScenarioToUpdate = new List<Test_Scenario__c>();
      List<Test_Campaign__c> TestCampToUpdate = new List<Test_Campaign__c>();
   
    for(Test_Campaign__c tc : Trigger.new){
        for (Test_Scenario__c Testsc : TS){ 
            if(Testsc.Test_Campaign__c == tc.Core_Campaign_Model__c){
                 Testsc.Test_Campaign__c = TC.Id;
                TestCampToUpdate.add(tc.clone(false, false, false, false));
                TestScenarioToUpdate.add(Testsc);
            }
        }
    }
    update TestScenarioToUpdate;
    
}
```

This trigger link records based on some criteria .

- if I insert new `Test_Campaign__c` and I select `Core_Campaign_Model__c` which have related records so new created `Test_Campaign__c` will have the related records linked to it

My need is to clone record from new `Core_Campaign_Model__c` and insert them into the new created `Test_Campaign__c`, is there any suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at the [SObject methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).  Search for clone.

Comment: Use the `clone()` method provided by the SObject class? There's not really enough information here to go into more detail than that. This site thrives on details (it's possible to be too detailed, but that's a lot harder than not providing enough details). Please [edit] your question to give us a better idea of what you're trying to do

Comment: Code updated @DerekF

Comment: If I'm understanding your update correctly, it sounds like you need to `insert TestCampToUpdate`. The name of `TestCampToUpdate` is a bit misleading, but if you `clone` a `Test_Campaign__c` record and _don't_ copy the ID, it is a new record and will need to be inserted, rather than updated (since it won't have an ID).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `clone` method to clone any SObject in Apex. [It takes up to 4 optional parameters, all of which are ***false*** by default](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm):

**clone(preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber)**

- *preserveId*: keeps the ID of the SObject you're cloning.
- *isDeepClone*: This one is a bit harder to understand. If `true`, then the relationship fields (e.g. master-detail, lookup) on the source object are duplicated in memory. Meaning, if you clone A to B and change the fields on B, A will be unaffected. If this is `false` and you manipulate B after cloning it from A, it has the side-effect of updating object A.
- *preserveReadonlyTimestamps*: Copies `CreatedById`, `CreatedDate`, `LastModifiedById`, and `LastModifiedDate` to the clone.
- *preserveAutonumber*: Copies auto-number fields from the source object.

Your use-case will dictate how you set these parameters. **edit**: As Phil W. pointed out below, `clone` is only aware of the fields and values that are currently in memory when you call `clone` on an object. So if you want to copy *all fields* from an object to a new object, *all fields must be queried for or available in the current context*. A trigger removes the burden of querying as all of a record's fields will be available in that context.

Example:

```java
Account sourceAccount = new Account(
    Name = 'Alfa'
);
insert sourceAccount; 
System.debug(sourceAccount);
/* 
sourceAccount looks like: {
    Id=001000000000001,
    Name='Alfa',
    CreatedDate=2020-11-20,
    ...
}
*/

Account cloneAccount = sourceAccount.clone(true, false, true);
cloneAccount.Name = 'Bravo';
System.debug(cloneAccount);
/* 
cloneAccount looks like: {
    Id=001000000000001,
    Name='Bravo',
    CreatedDate=2020-11-20,
    ...
}
*/
```

Comment: Worth noting that the clone will only contain field values for those populated fields in the original SObject. That's fine if you invoke the clone method in a trigger, for example, since triggers populate all fields.

Comment: Trigger updated